# How to delete files that are not present in another directory?

Tags: ant, delete-file, fileset

I have two directories, let's call them `src` and `build`. My build system works so that for all files with mtime more recent in `src` than in `build` it copies the file from `src` to `buid` and does some transformations (minification, versioning, etc.). Otherwise skips as the file is considered up to date.

This however poses a problem when source file is deleted, as its built version is still present in `build` and gets into map file generated afterwards.

```
$ ls src
example1.js
example2.js

$ ant do-the-stuff
...

$ ls build
example1.js
example1-12345.min.js
example2.js
example2-23456.min.js
.map

$ cat .map
example1.js=example1-12345.min.js
example2.js=example2-23456.min.js

$ rm src/example2.js
$ ant do-the-stuff
...

$ cat .map
example1.js=example1-12345.min.js
example2.js=example2-23456.min.js
```

Is there a way to delete files not present in another directory with Ant? From set theory point of view it's a simple A\B operation.

This is what I have tried already but didn't work:

```
<delete dir="build">
    <exclude name="src/*" />
</delete>

<delete dir="build">
    <exclude>
        <fileset name="src" />
    </exclude>
</delete>

<delete dir="build">
    <fileset dir="build/*">
        <not>
            <present targetdir="src" />
        </not>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

Answer (score 3):

"Is there a way to delete files not present in another directory with Ant"
yes, use [delete task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html)  with a [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) using a [presentselector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect), f.e.

```
<fileset dir="/home/rosebud/temp/dir1" includes="*.jar" id="srcfileset">
 <present present="srconly" targetdir="/home/rosebud/temp/dir2"/>
</fileset>
<echo>Files only in /home/rosebud/temp/dir1 => ${toString:srcfileset}</echo>
<delete>
 <fileset refid="srcfileset"/>
</delete>
```

would delete all files only present in /home/rosebud/temp/dir1
for the other way around use :

```
...
 <not>
  <present present="srconly" targetdir="/home/rosebud/temp/dir2"/>
 </not>
...
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/12847012/130683 for another example using the present selector

Answer (score 0):

In Ant there are tasks [`depend`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html) and [`dependset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/dependset.html) for this.

These delete targets for which sources are newer, but I guess this might be ok for you.

In this very concrete case, `depend` seems to be the right one.

Example:

```
<depend srcdir="src" destdir="build"/>
```

Comment: I think it does the opposite of what I want. I have no problems with maintaining EXISTING files in sync. I need however to get rid of those DELETED from src/, so that they don't stay in build/, and not get into map file.